# ANDROID: How to have a canvas the responds to a user touch

Tags: android, canvas, draw

I'm new to canvas and animations, but I was wondering where the actually coding for where the user touches would be! In an example is saw like this,

```
switch (event.getAction()) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
    break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
    drawPath.reset();
    break;
default:
    return false;
```

I'm not to sure how this works. If the app I am wanting to create responds to move a ball up responding to when the user tapped, how should I do this? (think flappy bird but the screen moves up)

In the MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:, you can't use canvas.getWidth() or any parameters like that to see where the user touched.

Thanks for any and all help :)

Answer (score 0):

TO get where the user touched you'd use event.getX() and event.getY().  You wouldn't use any canvas operations at all.

Comment: However, I am looking for a certain square. Like where would i put the code for something like if(x > squareX && x < squareX +drawable.width()){ etc, then do this. If I click on a drawable, I was this to happen. Where should I put the if statement and where should the code be for what happens?